# How to snap to the point of intersection?

Tags: snapping

This is what I'm trying to do -
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the link - there are definitely some nice workarounds however it doesn't fully address my issue as I need a way to snap to an intersection rather than create a vertex at that point. Though I'm ok with the proposed methods, it's still too much of a hassle. Too bad Blender doesn't have such a snapping option.